# error : X.shape[1] = 1 should be equal to 9, the number of features at training time

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I am trying different ml algorithms on a dataset to predict football player's market price. I'm stuck while using SVR. The dataset's dimensions are : 461 rows * 9 columns . Here is the code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('1603428153-5e748a2d5fc288e9f69c5f86.csv')
dataset.columns
X = dataset.drop(['name','club','nationality','position','age_cat','new_signing','new_foreign','big_club'],axis=1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X1 = sc_X.fit_transform(X1)
y = y.reshape(-1,1)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(y)

# Fitting SVR to the dataset
from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf',epsilon=1.0)
regressor.fit(X1, y)

pred=regressor.predict(X_test)
print(regressor.score(X_test,y_test))
print(r2_score(y_test,pred))
```

Here in the line "pred = regressor.predict(X_test), it throws the error : X.shape[1] = 9 should be equal to 1, the number of features at training time. Please help

Comment: are you using a jupyter notebook by chance

Comment: Because as posted, your code calls `X1` before it is defined.  This kind of issue crops up frequently if you work in a stateful environment

Comment: Solved...Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ran this locally yet, but it looks like you may have called `X1` during your `fit_transform` step. I think you wanted to call `X` instead?

```
# X1 = sc_X.fit_transform(X1)
X1 = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
```